# Github ssh -T git@github.com shows old username which is nowhere to be found

Tags: git, github

`git config --list` shows me my correct new username (same for the global one), and the correct ssh push/fetch paths. But if I type `ssh -T git@github.com`, I am greeted by my old username, which I am currently not using.

I even checked the Windows credential manager and deleted all credentials; still the same effect. This old name is nowhere to be found.  What am I missing?

**EDIT:**
It has to do something with the `ssh-agent` being unable to retrieve my ssh-keys. If I manually add the ssh-keys to the agent it works. This arises two questions:
1) Where does the old username come from?
2) Why doesn't it auto-add my ssh-keys? They are in the $HOME/.ssh path, and I added the [Auto-launching ssh-agent on Git for Windows](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases) script to my `.bashrc`

**EDIT2:** Thanks to Lee's question, the issue is solved.  I can answer both questions which arised:
1) The old username comes from the id_rsa ssh-key.
2) The script only works if the naming of the key is exactly id_rsa. I missunderstood the documentation, thinking that $HOME/.ssh/mykey_rsa would work as well for the script, but this is not the case.
So, if anyone stumbles upon this:  Delete (save it if you still need it/rename) your id_rsa, and create a new id_rsa. This will solve the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not currently using'? Does the old github account still exist? Which SSH key is associated with that account?

Comment: Thanks for this question, it really helped me find the root cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make this clearer and more explicit:

1. Remember, there are at least *two* computers involved here: yours, where you're storing various files and settings, and GitHub's.  (GitHub use multiple machines, but they pretend to be a single computer.)
2. Your computer calls up the GitHub one over the Internet, as if making a phone call.  Your computer then hands over some form of *credentials*.  Their computer inspects these credentials, and decides whether you are who you claim to be.
3. The credentials you hand over depend on *how* you make the call.  If you make the call using `https://...`, Git uses a *credential manager*.  Each OS has its own set of credential managers that Git can use, so the process here is *very* different on Windows, MacOS, Linux, and so on.  If you make the call using `ssh://...`, all OSes share enough of a common SSH code base that they all proceed in almost the same way at this point, although there are still OS-specific items that come up.

Since you're using SSH, the (single, but see below) credential you hand over is your *public ssh key* (using encryption as well, using your private key—see [this Digital Ocean article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-the-ssh-encryption-and-connection-process) for instance).  Your ssh key is stored in an OS-specific (and configurable) location.  In your particular case it was `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.  The name without `.pub` on the end is the *private* key, and these keys come in pairs.

When GitHub receive your key, they look it up in a giant table in which they keep *every key that everyone has given them*.  Your key never matches anyone else's key.  The key you gave them has a *user name* associated with it, back when you gave them that key.  Since only you have this key (and the private key that go with it), GitHub can now be sure that you are who you just claimed to be.

The claim happened entirely via this public key.  If you don't want to claim to be that person any more, hand over a *different* public key.  [You'll also need to log in to Git, and give them the new or updated public key.](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)  This must happen after you've generated the public/private key-pair, and before you use `ssh` to connect your computer and your Git to their computer with their Git.

There are two important things to be aware of here, that complicate this otherwise relatively simple picture.  Again, the **simplified** picture is:  **There is one key-pair.  You store, on GitHub, your public key from this one key-pair.  Later, you have your Git call up GitHub via `ssh`.  Your `ssh` and their `sshd` exchange some data.  Your ssh uses encryption using *both* keys from your key-pair.  They now know that you are you because they can match everything up using their copy of your public key, *and* only *you* have the *private* key that was able to unlock the data.**  But you might want to keep more than one key-pair in *your* computer, and that complicates everything.

#### Giving different keys to different recipients

The common base ssh software can try various key-pairs in sequence.  See the section below on multiple keys for the (many and complex) details.  You can, however, tell it to try *one particular* file, choosing that one file based on the host to which you're ssh-ing, using a `config` file (`$HOME/.ssh/config`).  For instance, suppose that you want all connections to `github.com` to use only the private-and-public key-pair stored in the files `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.github` and `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.github.pub`.  Then:

```
Host github.com
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.github
```

will do that.  The first line, `Host github.com`, tells SSH that the entries below apply to sessions with a host named `github.com`.  (Glob patterns are allowed here, so if your work or school or whatever has hosts whose names match `*.example.com`, you can use such a glob pattern.)

The second line, `IdentitiesOnly yes`, overrides identities offered through *ssh-agent*.  You may or may not want to do this!  If you are using ssh-agent to provide identities, this defeats (at least some of) the agent's offers, on purpose.  See the details in the next section.

The last line, `IdentityFile path`, sets the name of the key or key-pair file.  `ssh` will add or remove `.pub` as necessary here.  (There is some variation in ssh versions and you may want or not want the `.pub`; use what works for you.)

Both `ssh` (the user facing command that *you* use to connect to a server) and `sshd` (the command on the server to which your ssh connects) are very configurable.  For a complete list of ssh configuration options, see [the `ssh_config` manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config).

#### Agents and `IdentityFile` entries

In each host configuration section of your `$HOME/.ssh/config` file, you can put in multiple `IdentityFile` lines.  If you do, ssh will offer *each* key, until one is accepted, or it runs out of keys to offer.

If you have *no* `IdentityFile` lines, your SSH has some built in defaults.  These vary slightly from one SSH version (and OS) to another; see your own `ssh_config` documentation for *your* system's list, but the documentation I linked above says:

> The default is ... `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_dsa` for protocol version 2.

(DSA encryption is at least deprecated, and mostly totally unsupported, now.  ECDSA encryption is, I think, the current favorite, although encryption is not my area.)

In the absence of `IdentitiesOnly yes`, SSH may *also* offer *all* the identities—i.e., keys—provided by your *SSH Agent*.  The agent is a helper system that allows you to ship keys from one computer (your most-trusted one) to another, without storing them in *files* on the less-trusted computer.  The way this works looks relatively simple, big-picture-wise: when your ssh contacts some other host *H*, if you *didn't* say `IdentitiesOnly yes`, your ssh contacts your agent and ask *it* for keys to try.  It will try these keys on host *H*, one at a time.  If none of them work, it still has any locally-stored file and/or the ones listed in `IdentityFile` entries.

The details, however, are complicated.  First, note that the agent itself comes in two parts.  (These aren't necessarily separate programs, but it's easier to think about the system by describing each as a separate thing.)

- One part runs on the machine that you *do* trust (that has the keys stored in files).
- The other part runs on the machine that you're logging in to, via `ssh`, from that trusted machine.

Both machines start up an agent.  Sometimes you might run more than one agent on each machine, and again the details vary a bit from one OS to another—for instance, on MacOS, simply being logged in creates an agent, which all of your Terminal windows can then share.  From any Terminal window, you run `ssh less-trusted-machine` and start a new session on the less-trusted machine, and *it* brings up an agent as well, or uses one that you already have, or whatever.

You then now use Git on the *second* machine.  The less-trusted machine's ssh notices that there is an agent, and asks it for keys.  This agent contacts the agent on your more-trusted machine.  The agent on your more-trusted machine retrieves the keys and hands them over, or doesn't, all depending on whatever rules the two agents and various ssh instances are using.

Hence, when you're using an agent, the set of keys that the less-trusted machine *has* (or has access to) depends on what the agent on the *more*-trusted machine does.  So that's why this picture is complicated.

If you're not using an agent at all, or if, in the command-line interpreter where you're going to run `ssh` or have Git run `ssh`, you defeat the agent entirely,<sup>1</sup> the ssh that you run—or that Git runs—has access only to those identities (key-pairs) that you have in your `$HOME/.ssh/` or other OS-specific location where you have put such keys.  It still has access to *all* the keys you have put there, of course.  The `IdentitiesOnly yes` line in your config now means *use only the files I listed here.*  That's pretty straightforward: you list the files—or rather, one of each pair of files, and put the keys in the files.

If you *are* using an agent, the ssh that you or Git run has access to additional key-pairs.  Adding `IdentitiesOnly` here is complicated.  It won't stop your ssh from contact the agent—but each of the keys the agent returns has an *identity*.  You can tell the ssh you're running *use only the identities that match the files I specified in the `IdentityFile` section.*  What this means is that **you can store just the public key**, rather than both public and private key-pair files.  If you don't trust this machine much—the one I've been calling the less-trusted machine—then that gives you a way to keep your private key off it entirely, using the agent.

Last, on whichever machine you *do* store both public and private keys, you can *encrypt* them.  You'll now need to enter a password or passphrase to unlock them.  This can get annoying, but using an agent, you can unlock them once for the agent, and trust the agent to keep them secure in memory.  (How *much* you can trust this agent ... well, that's another problem entirely!)

#### Too many keys

The actual unlocking and testing whether you are who you claim to be generally happens inside `sshd`, the server-side software that implements ssh.  Your ssh calls up their sshd and hands over a key, with all the encryption protocols and such.  They try it in a lock using the public key part of the key-pair, and it works ... or doesn't—and if it *didn't* work, they may offer you more tries.  This is configurable, on the server.

Now, suppose you are using an agent and have fifty (50) different keys stored in your agent.  Your ssh, on whichever computer you're on—however trusted it is—gets one key from the agent and gives it to an sshd, and it's no good.  Your ssh gets the next key from the agent, and tries that one, and it's not the right key either.  It's like you're fumbling through 50 keys on a key ring, not even looking at each key, and trying it in a lock.  After a while, the sshd on the server gets alarmed by the repeated failures: it looks like you're trying to break in.

The actual number of tries allowed varies from one server to another, because it's configurable.  But if you do have a *lot* of keys, it's a good idea to try the *right* key (only, or first).  To do that, you'll want to use the `IdentitiesOnly yes` line, **whether or not you use an agent**:

- If you do not use an agent, `IdentitiesOnly yes` means *only use the public/private key pairs listed in each `IdentityFile` configuration entry here.*  So you list the right one, and your ssh uses the right one, and it fits the lock and their sshd likes you, and all is good.
- If you do use an agent, `IdentitiesOnly yes` means *use the agent's key(s) that matches the public-key listed in the `IdentityFile` configuration entry or entries here*.  So you list the right one, and your ssh uses the right one, and as before, all is good.

If you use an agent, but have only a few keys—just one or two or maybe even up to about six or so, depending on the sshd configurations at the servers you call up—you don't *need* the `IdentitiesOnly yes` and `IdentityFile` lines.  But they won't *hurt*, as long as you get them right.

#### Putting all of this together

- You can (and in fact must) store the key-pair files somewhere, on a mostly-trusted computer.  You can *encrypt* these as well so that you must type in a password or passphrase to unlock them, although this can get annoying.  An agent can help.  You may (probably will) need to *load* keys into that agent using `ssh-add`.
- When you ssh from one computer to another, you can have your agent *forwarded*, to a new agent on the next computer.  The second and any subsequent computers in the chain need the *public* key of the key-pair, to verify that you are you, but if you've set up agent forwarding, they don't need the private key.
- Each computer in this chain of trust—that you `ssh` into from a more-trusted computer—takes the encrypted data you send initially, as you start up the ssh session.  They use a stored *public key*, that you have somehow (any way you like / can), already stored onto the less-trusted computer, to see if you know the *private* key.  If you do, you must actually be you.
- Except for the fact that they've fancied up their `sshd`, GitHub is really no different: it's just a less-trusted computer that you "log into" (as `git@github.com`).  They take the key you give them and look it up—but instead of just having *one* key for *you*, they have one key for *every account that exists on GitHub*.  They try the key you give them and see if it works in the lock for Alice.  Nope?  Must not be Alice; try it in the lock for Bob.  No?  Try Carol—and so on down the line, until maybe it unlocks Fred, or Rita, or Zack.  When they get to the stored `.pub` key that *works*, well, that must be who *you* are.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>In a shell session, you'll see an environment variable, `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, that holds the path name by which an `ssh` you run *on* that machine contacts the agent.  If you override or unset the environment variable, this defeats the agent.

To see if you have an agent active, and if so, what keys it has access to, use `ssh-add -l`.

<sup>2</sup>Trying one identity at a time like this, linearly through thousands or millions of identities, is much too slow, so GitHub must necessarily use a different strategy internally.  But the effect is the same: you gave them an identity bit-string, via your public/private key-pair and encryption, from your ssh to their sshd.  They use the collected authorized keys for *everyone* and find a unique *someone* in that pile, and whoever they found, that's *you*.  If they don't find anyone, they reject the key, and your ssh can go on to offer another key, up to whatever limit they have set in *their* sshd.

Comment: What happens when I have several keys in my .ssh folder?
Github seems to magically expect the wrong one. Can I somehow tell my computer, which ssh-private-key credentials to use on that call?

Comment: I added a section on specifying particular key-pairs for particular hosts.

Comment: then again, what I don't understand - you said the ssh-agent would try all keys in there, so my logical explanation for why it wasnt working - it was fetching the wrong key - is invalid. Why does it not work/I have to-readd the key every session for the agent to recognize that key?

Comment: @Leviathan: are you using ssh-agent, or not? Are you configuring ssh to ignore the agent, or not? Note that the ssh_config documentation says that in the absence of additional information, it will try all agent keys, and *one* of the file keys. I'll add another section on multiple keys. Remember that GitHub has only *one* public key for *you* and you use their web interface to upload a new one. As you offer keys, they'll try them in this lock, and whichever key you offer fits, that must mean that you are you.

Comment: I've fancied up the answer a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You’re mentioning that you are using Windows, therefore these are the steps you need to follow:

We need to remove the old credentials:

`Control Panel >> User Account >> Credential Manager >> Windows Credential >> Generic Credential`
Remove your *GIT credentials*.

After that, you have to type your new account credentials:

```
$ git config --global user.name "Bob"
$ git config --global user.email "bob@example.com"
```

Comment: "I even checked the Windows credential manager and deleted all credentials". I have done that already.