# How to change ssh git user

Tags: git, authentication, github, ssh

I am using git with multiple accounts (two) on the same local machine. I created a new ssh-key for the new user (id_rsa_new_user) and I have changed the config file accordingly to allow multiple users, by adding

```
#new_user's account
Host github.com-new_user
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_new_user
```

I logged-in with new git credential by

```
 git config --local user.name "new_user_ID"
 git config --local user.email "new_user@email.com"
```

and I checked that the login is successful by running

```
git config --global --list
```

Problem:
when I run

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

I am still logged in with the previous user, and this does not allow me to git push or pull properly. How can I authenticate myself via ssh on github with the new user?

Thank you all

Comment: Should the git url be `git@github.com-new_user/repo.git`? Or something like that. `git config` has nothing to do with the ssh key as far as I know

Comment: See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60404159/1256452) about why `ssh -T git@github.com` shows the wrong user. In your case it may be a lack of `IdentitiesOnly yes` in your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

When you define an entry in your ~/.ssh/config file, you need to use that entry in your SSH URL, or it won't select the right private key:

```
ssh -Tv github.com-new_user
```

No need to add `git@` in front of that SSH URL: everyhing is already specified in the config file.

As noted, `user.name`/`user.email` are for commit authorship and play no role in authentication (SSH or HTTPS)